# How to access variables of parent class from extended class?

Tags: php, object

The following code gives me an error

```
class One{    
    public $var = 10;
}

class Two extends One{
    public $var = 20;
    function __construct(){
        $this->var = parent::$var;
    }
}

$two = new Two();
echo $two->var;
```

Comment: I think this case is totally wrong about OOP concept. If you do NOT need to override parent value, just use parent value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get like this `parent::$var` (so static), define `var` as `static` both in One and Two.

This will work;

```
class One {    
    public static $var = 10;
}

class Two extends One {
    public static $var = 20;

    public function __construct() {
        // this line creates a new property for Two, not dealing with static $var
        $this->var = parent::$var;
        // this line makes real change
        // self::$var = parent::$var;
    }
}

$two = new Two();
echo $two->var; // 10
echo $two::$var; // 20, no changes
echo Two::$var;  // 20, no changes

// But I don't recommend this usage
// This is proper for me; self::$var = parent::$var; instead of $this->var = parent::$var;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are overriding your variable. If you need some kind of default/read only in the abstract/parent class, try something like this:

```
<?php

class One{    
    private $var = 10;

        public function getVar(){
            return $this->var;
        }
}

class Two extends One{
    public $var;
    function __construct(){
        $this->var = parent::getVar();
    }
}

$two = new Two();
echo $two->var;

?>
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel - Can you give some sample code of using the parent keyword to access a public property of a parent class?  I notice in your example you accessed a parent method.

Comment: @user784637: You don't; it's already on `$this` if it's `public`. No effort required.

Comment: There is not specific code for that because every public property belongs to the current class. I mean if in the parent class the var is public, in the child class $this->var is the way to access it. Also public vars can be re-declared(override) in the child class(it is what are you doing). That is the reason because I'm suggesting you to define that default value as private, because private vars cannot be overridden.

Answer (score 0):

That's built-in; just don't redeclare the variable. [(Demo)](http://codepad.viper-7.com/KpriIG)

```
class One {
    public $var = 10;
}

class Two extends One {
}

$two = new Two();
echo $two->var;
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as the variable is either `public` or `protected`, then it will be inherited by the subclass.

```
class One{    
    public $var = 10;
}

class Two extends One{
    public $var = 20;
}

class Three extends One{
}

$a = new One();
echo $a->var; // 10

$b = new Two();
echo $b->var; // 20

$c = new Three();
echo $c->var; // 10
```